# Flex and Java Integration

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex3

I want to connect Java and FLEX. 
I have never used Java and also Java is not installed on my PC.
So From Installation of Java to Calling Java Method from FLEX and Receive the Result from Java to FLEX i need steps so any one help me to connect Java and FLEX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go through the following steps. This will surely helpful to you...

1   Install JDK in your system

2   Copy apache tomcat server in your c drive

3   Set Environment Variable
    (1)  Variable Name  :   JAVA_HOME
        Variable Value  :   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
    (2) Variable Name   :   CATALINE_HOME
        Variable Value  :   C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.35

4   Update the Path Environment Variable in Variable Value
    Add tha fillowing Path
    (1)C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin
    (2)C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin

5   Create a Blazeds folder in webapps folder and extract the blazeds.war file

```
    Two folder there (1)WEB-INF (2)META-INF
```

6   Create a folder name example in C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\FlexJavaIntegration\WEB-INF\classes

7   Create a Java file in example folder content of java file is below

```
    package example;

    import java.util.Date;

    public class HelloWorld 
    {
        public HelloWorld() 
        {

        }
        public String getHelloWorld(String name,String name1) 
        {
            String result = null;
            result = name + " and " + name1;
            return result;
        }
        public String getCurrentDate(String name)
        {
            String result = null;
            result = " Current Date is:" + new Date();
            return result;
        } 
    }
```

8   Complile the .java file in CMD

```
    javac HelloWorld.java
```

9   Go to folder C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\FlexJavaIntegration\WEB-INF\flex and edit the remoting-config.xml file and add the destination

```
<destination id="helloworld">
    <properties>
        <source>example.HelloWorld</source>
    </properties>
    <adapter ref="java-object" />
</destination>
```

10  Start Tomcat Server from CMD 
    Go to bin folder of Tomcat server folder 
    Run startup.bat file in cmd and start Tomcat server 
    check: "localhost:8080" URl in your browser
    and if you want to shutdown the tomcat serve write follwing command in CMD
    shutdown.bat

11  Create New Flex Application 
    Select Server Technology - J2EE

12  Click Next and Set Following Properties

```
Root Folder :    C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\blazeds
Root URL        :   http://localhost:8080/blazeds
Context Root    :   /blazeds

And Validate Configuration
```

13  The Remote Object Syntax is as follows

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="ro" destination="helloworld" source="example.HelloWorld" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="faultHandler(event)"/>

    ---------destination in RemoteObject is id of destination in remoting-config.xml
    ---------source in RemoteObject is source of destination in remoting-config.xml
```

14   Now Call the Java Method as follows

```
<mx:Button label="Get Hello World!" click="ro.getHelloWorld(txt1.text,txt2.text)"/>
<mx:Button label="Get Time" click="ro.getResults(txt1.text)" />

    Here ro is id of RemoteObject and getHelloWorld & getResults is method from JAVA file.
```

15  You get result from java class file

**NOTE :** YOU NEED TO INSTALL THE BLAZEDS AND APACHE TOMCAT SERVER ON YOUR PC

Comment: Nice explanation. Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite well described in this [java world entry](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-javaee-flex-1.html)

You have a couple of choices to make Flex talk to Java:
   - object remoting
   - SOAP
   - other HTTP based webservices 
   -...

If I was you, I would be trying to go for a lightweight restful method of getting your data from one to the other, so you can switch technology if you have too.