# How can I call a Flex/Flash/Actionscript method from Java?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex

I have a Flex/Java project in which I am using a third party application/sdk to communicate with the back end.

I would like to write a Java test class that can call a certain flex method and get the result.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

There are plenty of solutions for how to call java methods from flex ([Flex and Java Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159973/flex-and-java-integration)) , but I can't find anything on how to call flex methods from java..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't call methods on the client directly, but you can use push technology to notify the client that it should execute a method. Google for Flex [Consumer](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/messaging/Consumer.html) to find more info on how it works.

Comment: push technology would still have no interaction with the client, usually a broker has sends data over a stream and the clients listens (with LCDS and similar this is abstracted). relating more to your post I have never personally a use case for a server calling a client to test code, something lower down the chain (thinking or stack) must be a bit off

Comment: What is the relationship between the Java code and the Flex code? For example, if the Flex code is embedded in Java as a plugin such as ActiveX, you should be able to call methods on the plugin that on the other side will hook into ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sort of. You can use GraniteDS+Tide for data push initiated server-side.

http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/10.+Data+Push